# How to make a list of variables in flutter?

Tags: list, dart, flutter

I want to create a list in flutter that contains variable. Now when I am trying to edit the contents of the list, it actually gets stored in the list itself. For eg.,

```
static var _ratingSelected = "";
static var _disconnectSelected = "";
static var _uTypeSelected = "";

List finalSelectedList = [_uTypeSelected,_disconnectSelected,_ratingSelected];
```

This is my list, when I will edit the list, like,

```
finalSelectedList[0] = "Main";
```

The output list will be like

```
finalSelectedList = ["Main",_disconnectSelected,_ratingSelected];
```

It will edit the finalSelectedList[0] position of the list but not the variable *_uTypeSelected*. **Is there any way so that the value gets stored in the variable *_uTypeSelected* and not at the position *finalSelectedList[0]*?**

Comment: Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your attempt, noting input and expected output.

Comment: When I store the value in the list at _0 position_, I want it to be stored actually in the variable __uTypeSelected_ and it should not edit the actual list (The list is only to contain those variables).

Comment: Strings are immutable, so you can't change the state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to do that. If you use `finalSelectedList[0].someProp = "Main";` where the variables are instances of some classes that have a `someProp` property, then it would work, because there is an additional abstraction. Strings are primitive values and copied by value when added to a list and therefore there is no connection left between list entry and variable.

```
class Foo {
  Foo(this.someProp);
  String someProp;
}
```

```
static var _ratingSelected = Foo("");
static var _disconnectSelected = Foo("");
static var _uTypeSelected = Foo("");

List finalSelectedList = [_uTypeSelected,_disconnectSelected,_ratingSelected];
```

```
finalSelectedList[0].someProp = "Main";
```